# PHP display image BLOB from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to display an image stored in the BLOB column in the database;

I fetch the data from the database with a SELECT perform no transformations on the data and display it with the following (from a script whose only output is the following):

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Please note chrome is displaying the content size as the correct size for the image as well as the correct mime type (`image/jpeg`). nothing is echoing out before the header and ive checked the blob in the database is correct. There is also no trailing whitespace before or after the `<?php ?>` tags.

chrome/IE displays an image icon but not the image itself. any ideas?

EDIT: image is got the from the database as such:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$row = $sth->fetch();
$image = $row['image'];
```

var_dump($image) gives:

```
string 'ÿØÿà�JFIF��x�x��ÿá�ZExif��MM�*�����������J��������Q�������Q������tQ������t�����† ��±ÿÛ�C�       

ÿÛ�CÿÀ�_"�ÿÄ����������� 
ÿÄ�µ���}�!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³    ´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ��������'... (length=60766)
```

Comment: Post what constitutes `$image` please (I.e. queries, etc)

Comment: @user2732663 Did you try my answer below?

Comment: try to save `$image` into binary file and open it, maybe data in DB is corrupted?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source code in the browser? Sometimes a PHP error or notice messes the output up.

Comment: You've not shown us the code which INSERTs the image - which is as important as the code for retrieving it.

Comment: It's seems like you are saving the image as is in binary, but you should convert it to base64. Also storing images in database is bad-practice. If you can change it, do it now or you will get performance problems. Try avoiding BLOB or TEXT fields. Save the filename and do something like `<img src="images/<?php echo $image->filename;?>" alt=".." title="..">`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try it like this.

**For inserting into DB**

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "DbName");
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);
$query = "INSERT INTO products (image) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $image);
$stmt->execute();
```

**For accessing image from Blob**

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "DbName");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';
```

Comment: i want to display this echo on html iframe. how this can be done?

Comment: Hello! I really appreciate this but what happens if the image is another format?

Comment: @CarlosMontiel, to save image into db is not a good practice. Save Image on directory and save its image name or path into database to access that image. Someone ask the question, I give the answer. that's it. : )

Comment: @CarlosMontiel, I am not sure but it will need to be work on other formats too like PNG or GIF etc.

Answer (score 18):

This is what I use to display images from blob:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image->load()) .'" />';
```

Comment: is $image a php object?

Comment: Working like charm! Thank you.. @ProgrammingNewb you can place your image data type in $image. it could be a PHP variable from $row["photo"];

Comment: nice to know it worked for you, I took a different approach, I created a folder in my server and store all images there, and i store the link of the image in my mysql database, then whenever I want to display an image, call the link stored in my database