# Diplaying blob image from Mysqli using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
 $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db')

$query="SELECT Binfile, Filetype FROM imagetable where imgid='$imgid'" ;
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$image=$row['Binfile'];
header("Content-type:".$row['Filetype']);

echo $image;
```

This is the code which I am using to display the image.
But it is giving an error like

The image `“http://lacalhost//viewimage.php?imgid=1”` cannot be displayed because it contain errors.

Help me to remove this error and display the image…

I wonder if I can use as `echo'img src='` type to display.

Comment: do you have `$imgid = $_GET['imgid']`?

Comment: Yes,it just above the query

Comment: Check the piece of code where the images go to the db. The source may be encoded. Then you should decode it before echoing.

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on? `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: what's the output of `$row['Filetype']` ? what's the output of `$row['Binfile'];`? please check it by yourself. Please mind you will not see any errors or messages because of `header("Content-type:"`. r

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql