# image not displayed from database, shows only unusual fonts

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to display the image from database but it shows only unusual fonts in place of image. I have tried this code:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "learndb");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
$myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo '<img src="'.$myrow["image-data"].'" >';
```

Comment: The `src` attribute of the `img` element is to specify the `URL` of an image resource, not the actual content. That is a difference.

Comment: extra `]` at `".$myrow[image-data]]`. ANd stop using mysql it is deprecated instead use `mysqli or POD`

Comment: @Saty that was only typing mistake.

Comment: `$myrow[image-data]` should be `$myrow['image-data']`

Comment: @NanaPartykar sorry but that too was typing mistake.

Comment: Why not post the actual code that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is in [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql), where you should add:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Into your code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

So in your case:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("learndb",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE id=$id",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $myrow['image-data'] ).'"/>'
```

And try not to use MySQL anymore, you can use MySQLi or PDO.