# How to use php select mysql field type of `blob`

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use php to connect  mysql and select field type of `blob` , but print result like '羂Z娛爌@c?驀' 
What should I do

see picture [image]

Comment: Going by the column name, it's encrypted data hence the output you're getting.

Comment: Here is the similar question with  answers - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Comment: Usually the blob field can be print like text fields with PHP but your filed  says encryptedPassword. Do you know what kind of encryption it is? If it is a two way encryption use MySQL DECODE() function if you know the key

Comment: this `blob` fields just a text ,This is I use Navicat export sql like ‘INSERT INTO `Entry` VALUES ('1', '1', 'asfdsdf', null, null, 'admin', 0x6AFE61AFEBF15628857F69FB1C037AD4, '3');
INSERT INTO `Entry` VALUES ('2', '1', 'å•Šæ˜¯å¦å¤§æ˜¯åœ°æ–¹', null, null, 'admindddd', 0x7D66B4A02109AC8D113A215C425CBFD6, '1');
INSERT INTO `Entry` VALUES ('3', '3', 'uid2', null, null, 'admin', 0xC11A8ACAA070401B63A711F2872C0F04, '3');     ‘0x7D66B4A02109AC8D113A215C425CBFD6’ is blob field 
’

Comment: you shouldn't encrypt passwords,

Comment: @self you should include that passwords definitely should be **hashed** instead. right now, you comment could be misinterpreted as "plain-text is okay". that said: OPs problem would most certainly be solved by using `password_hash()` and storing those hashes in a text-field instead of a blob-field.