# How can I display an image in Laravel 5.3 using *BLOB?

Tags: php, image, file, laravel-5, seed

To start, I'd like to know how to send an image from my **public folder**, I have a column `image` of type `MEDIUMBLOB` in my table named **movies**. I'm using `mysql_*` as my database connection.

This is my current seed:

```
public function(){
    DB::table('movies')->insert([
            'name' => 'La vida es bella',
            'score' => '0',
            'date' => '1999-2-26',
            'image' => ??????????               
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to input image data to your `MySQL` table, use the following structure of code:

```
DB::table('movies')->insert([
  'image' => file_get_contents( "public/images/image.jpg" )
]);
```

(I don't use `Laravel`, or the connection type you're using, that's just the way you insert `*BLOB` data into a database.

The main function to take away from this is `file_get_contents( IMAGE_LOCATION )`, which will get the raw image data and uses that as the blob, and if you wanted to pull it from the database you'd just have to pack it into the correct mime, like so:

```
$blob = ''; //from database
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $blob ).'"/>';
```

This is converting the data to a `DATAURI`, which you can read about [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) as a quick-to-read article.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it worked for you @nestorjodar and that such an old post helped out, I remember back to writing this answer - I legit could not get this to work myself (I was a newbie to PHP at the time) and I'm impressed my question actually had value. Haha 

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']))).'"/>';
```

try this code it is working for me,this is in to directly view the blob file which was submitted,

if you want to show the blob image stored in DB then is make a link which return the blob saved in DB and then give that link in *src* of image

like this

```
<img src="{{url('url_returning_blob_data_from_db')}}" />
```