# PHP Retrieve image from database error

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am attempting to recall an image from the database. I have established the image reaches the database properly, however when I pull the image down I get the Blob text that makes it up. How can I pull down the image in order to display the image?

```
<?php
    //libs
    include 'library/config.php';
    include 'library/opendb.php';
    //query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `upload` WHERE `postID`=".$elem["postID"].";";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // if results exist
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // assign db cont to variable
            $name = $row["name"];
            $size = $row["size"];
            $type = $row["type"];
            $content = $row["content"];
            // header info
            header("Content-length: $size");
            header("Content-type: $type");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
            //display image
            echo "img", $content;
         }
         include 'library/closedb.php';
     ?>
```

Comment: you've BLOB datatype in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)

Comment: Possibel duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Answer (score 1):

use

```
   $content = base64_encode($_row['content']);
```

to display a jpeg image.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$code_base64 = $row['content'];
$code_base64 = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','',$code_base64);
$code_binary = base64_decode($code_base64);
$image= imagecreatefromstring($code_binary);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```