# i want to retrieve image from mysql database but it is showing characters instead of image

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
```

//mysql connection code

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srsc");
```

//mysql query

```
$sql = "SELECT image1 FROM images WHERE imageID=1";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

//image tag

```
<img src="<?php echo $row["image1"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: what is stored in database column ??

Comment: Are you sure there are complete path of image in database?

Comment: Characters or Error??

Comment: what is the data-type of your column where you stored image? Also you stored image or it's path only? What error you get can you please add that to your question.

Comment: jpeg image is stored in blob type column name image1 and it is displaying characters not error

Comment: use like this:-  `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $result['image'] );?>"/>`

Comment: possible duplicate of:- [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20564797/4248328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty simple. You tell us what are you storing in your database table. I mean your are storing the image itself or image path (including only image name) in database.
If you are storing image path (name) then you need to give right path while accessing image and if your are storing image itself in blob form then here is [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql) for you.