# Laravel image encrypt and store into db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, encryption, file-upload

I need user image content to be encrypted and store into database  and then decrypt before display .My code in controller to encrypt,

```
public function savePicture(Request $request)
{
     $file = Input::file('pic');
     $img = Image::make($file);
     Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));

     $picture = new Picture;
     $picture->name = $request->get('name');
     $picture->pic = $img;
      $picture->pic=Crypt::encrypt(file_get_contents($file));
      //dd($picture);
     $picture->save();

}
```

When I run this code I got the error **PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away (SQL: insert into `pictures` (`name`, `pic`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)...**
How do I solve solve this?

Comment: Why does it need to be encrypted? And why store it in the database?

Comment: I need my images to be secure what else 'll be

Comment: Is there anyway to do this or it(encrypt & decrypt)   doesn't need?

Comment: @saranya Please refer to this : [Using PHP to encrypt image for storage in MySQL BLOB then decrypt and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396925/using-php-to-encrypt-image-for-storage-in-mysql-blob-then-decrypt-and-print). See if it can help.