# How to populate the value of an (html) input tag type file?

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

I have a template type view to allow users to create an event (like a social event...has name, description, image ect). I am using it for both the creation of an event and the editing of it.

I would like, when edit is selected elsewhere on the site, for the different fields to be populated with event details. I have this working for textboxes, textfeilds and selection type tags, but I am stuck on how you would do this with a file type.

This is what I have so far. This pattern worked for other inputs.

```
<input id="picture" class="form-control" type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*" value="{{($event == null ? "" : base64_encode($event->picture))}}" required autofocus/>
```

Just to be clear. I am not trying to fetch files off of peoples computers. The file is in my database (blob). All I want to do is put it back in the input field.

Is this even possible? If not is there another solution that I should consider.

Thank you.

Comment: every answer is talking about setting value to "path/to/file"

Comment: this is why I add "Just to be clear. I am not trying to fetch files off of peoples computers. The file is in my database (blob). All I want to do is put it back in the input field" into my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do realize that it is a blob data right? the only way you can show the data is by putting it inside a `<img>` tag and decode the data from database. to edit the image, you need to create an input for new upload.

like this [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

Comment: Thanks. I have an idea to do what I want in a different way. I understand now why i can't be done.