# Trying to get data from 2 databases with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have to make a booking system for a school project im really close but then this problem occured, which i cant solve.

So i hoped you guys could help me out :)

This is the PHP code getting data from the database (formulier.php):

```
<div id="room1" style="margin-left: 10%;"><br><br>
    <img src=”source.php?id=2” width="150" height="150" />&nbsp;
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2005-01-25'";
    /* SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2' */
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "HERE COMES THE DESCRIPTION &nbsp;";
            echo "&nbsp; check-in: ". $row["dt"] ." | check-out: ". $row["dt2"] ." ";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "An error occured, Please choose another date.";
    }
    $connect->close();
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input required type="submit" id="Reserve" name="Reserve" value="Book Now"  style="margin-left: 0.4%;">
    </form>
    <hr style="width: 65%;">
</div>

<div id="room1" style="margin-left: 10%;"><br><br>
    <img src=”source2.php?id=1” width="150" height="150" />&nbsp;
    <?php
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2100-01-25'";
    /* SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2' */
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$query2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)) {
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "HERE COMES THE DESCRIPTION &nbsp;";
            echo "&nbsp; check-in: ". $row2["dt"] ." | check-out: ". $row2["dt2"] ." ";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "An error occured, Please choose another date.";
    }
    $connect->close();
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input required type="submit" id="Reserve" name="Reserve" value="Book Now"  style="margin-left: 0.4%;">
    </form>
    <hr style="width: 65%;">
</div>
```

---

This is the PHP code for getting the image in the database (source.php):

```
$query = "select * from images WHERE id = 2";
$stmt = $connect->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if( $num ){
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    print $row['data'];
    exit;
}else{
}
```

---

This is for the second image (source2.php):

```
$query = "select * from images WHERE id = 1";
$stmt = $connect->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if( $num ){
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    print $row['data'];
    exit;
}else{
}
```

---

These are the databases:

```
TABLE IMAGES
========================================
id | name          | data
========================================
1  | sample image  |[BLOB - 31,9 KiB]
2  | sample image2 |[BLOB - 370,8 KiB]
```

---

```
TABLE DT_TB
========================================
id | dt          | dt2
========================================
1  | 2004-10-26  | 2005-01-25
```

---

```
TABLE DT_TB10
========================================
id | dt          | dt2
========================================
1  | 2006-01-01  | 2007-01-25
```

---

This is the outcome: https://gyazo.com/e3263b030bd2a367e86d39db262551ba

So my problem is basically that **it wont show the images from the database and
that the second "booking" will show an error and not the same data as the first "booking".**

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a first year student, so have mercy with my coding skills :)

Comment: How did you stored your pic ? Why not store the url pic. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql for blob stockage

Comment: Shouldn't the Image query be `$query = "select * from images WHERE id = ?";` instead of a hard-coded `1`? I will be surprised if it works the way you do it. Look at the Image with a browser and then view source and add error handling to the Images code.

Comment: You've literally set the source of the image to "source.php?id=2" Save the image as a URL not a blob, because that is what the src attribute on an image tag expects to get.

Answer (score 0):

Guys you can use this as an example but i've fixed my problem :).

You never close your $connection mid way.

```
$connect->close();
```

was used 2 times but its only used when you actually want to close your connection with your database.

As for the images, @Rick Calder has a good explanation about it.

thanks for the help.