# Can i use group_concat () for for images?

Tags: php, html, mysql, group-concat

Can I use `group_concat()` function to retrieve image from the database?

Using it the images are displayed as broken because maybe it's not reading image name properly?

```
$sql="SELECT product.*, group_concat(images.image) as imag FROM product LEFT JOIN images on product.id=images.pid group by product.id";
```

the loop for displaying image:

```
foreach(explode('.',$row['imag']) as $url)
 {?>

   <td><?php  $imageURL = 'pictures/'.$url;?>
   <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></td>

   <?php
}
```

This is what I'm getting as output:

[image: output]

Comment: Since your images do not load properly i assume that they aren't implemented in the DB as an Blob. This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Comment: but if im not using this ... using just simple inner join only i get image properly.. it display properly...

Comment: they are reading image names properly but while im displaying it on table it is not proper... butit is working well with all other innr join and queries

Comment: Can you show me what you get when you use inner join? Don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: i think it iis reading the all image name as a single line and breaking it

Comment: You need comma insteas of dot here - `explode(',',$row['imag']) as $url)` as I wrote in my answer

Comment: omgggg i got itt i got answr thank youuuuu thank you so much

Comment: Why dont you var_dump the query and see what you get as an output?

Comment: i got the answer....splash58 helped.. im getting proper output now...... Thanks for the help:D