# Not able to retrieve blob files from database where image is not loaded

Tags: php

While trying to retrieve blob values stored in database by using this way,I have problem.Please help me.

Blob value is stored in database in this way.
[image: Database]

```
 $criteria = [
            'lotItemNumber' => '',
            'artistName' =>$_POST['artistName'],
            'classification' =>$_POST['classification'],
            'producedYear' =>$_POST['producedYear'],
            'auctionDate' =>$_POST['auctionDate'],
            'textualDescription' =>$_POST['textualDescription'],
            'estimatedPrice' =>$_POST['estimatedPrice'],
            'image' =>'$temp'



              ];

$stmt = $stmt->insert($criteria);
```

And tried to retrieve in this way:
[image: Where I got stuck]

```
echo'<imgsrc="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'width="250" height="250">';
```

Clicking of this image icon produce 
[image]

Actual Image is 
[image: Actual Image is]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" width="250" height="250">';
          ^ space here                                                 ^ close quote and add space
```

**Also**, inserting values should be changed:

```
$criteria = [
    //...
    'image' => $temp,  // do not use single quotes
];
```

Comment: Still not working, it only increases width and height ,but the image is not displayed yet,

Comment: Also updated answer with correct usage of `$temp` while inserting.

Comment: I don't see `img` tag here.

Comment: `<img>` tag __not__ input field.

Comment: Could you please help me,on solving this on code.I will be grateful.

Comment: Fix issue with saving `$temp`.

Comment: I repeat __once again__ open html source code for a page __where__ you output image and check __what is there__ in `img` tag.