# Blob to image in browser

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to access image which is saved as blob, and the type of column is image which is saved using c# in mssql

While retrieving image is showing correctly using c# code

While accessing using php the image is broken

code which i have tried

```
 $image = imagecreatefromstring($stationDetail->cstatpic3); 
 ob_start();
 imagejpeg($image);
 $data = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .  base64_encode($data)  .     '" />';
 exit; 
also from this link
```

[PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

Comment: Unless the image you stored is _not_ a JPEG already, it makes rather little sense to use `imagecreatefromstring` followed `imagejpeg`. (What you receive from the database would need to be valid, binary image data to begin with, otherwise `imagecreatefromstring` could not do anything with it. But if you have valid, binary image data already, you could encode that as base64 directly, without the “detour” via `imagecreatefromstring` and back using `imagejpeg`.)

Comment: What have you done so far to actually debug this then? Have you at least checked what the generated HTML code looks like? Or verified that `$image` is a valid GD image resource?

Comment: @misorude image will be half so.. it is a valid  GD image resourc