# How do I append blob to dom?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to blobs, so I'm hoping for a little direction to save hours more of fruitless brute-force attempts.

I use the below php (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)) to return the base64-encoded image from my database to the get javascript function.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Photo'] ).'"==/>';
```

In javascript with console.log(this.responseText), I can see the encoding. But I'm not sure how it's appended to the dom so I can see the image in the webpage.

I'm used to appending to the dom in the following way:

```
var photo = document.createElement('img'); 
photo.src = X;
document.body.insertBefore(photo,document.body.firstChild);
```

But presumably some decoding is required on client side.

I'd be happy with a link to another stackoverflow question if you know a fitting one.

Most of the stackoverflow questions on the subject I have found ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag/7793098#7793098)) get to decoding or the echoing, but not an explicit treatment of including that image in the DOM.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If the `src` is formatted properly, there shouldn't be any additional fiddling necessary, I'd think. You'd want `x` to be `"data:image/jpeg;base64,1234<base64string here>=="` or something of the sort

Comment: Ah, OK. So you think then it should be quite straight forward then after I've got the echo back. Alright. Thanks I'll try some more using .insertBefore method and come back with results.

Comment: If `X` contains what it should, then yeah, I think that'd work. Look at the rendered JS to see what it's like to debug. (The `X` should not contain the `<img` tag, only the base64 part)

Comment: By 'rendered JS' do you just mean the webpage? Or is there a section in the console you are specifically referring to?

Comment: I mean the source HTML the client sees, like what you see when you do control-U

Comment: Ah, cool - thanks CertainPerformance. I will spend some more time trying with that confidence. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That worked. Thanks again CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as given by @CertainPerformance, is a trivial variation on the linked solutions given elsewhere.

Echoing back the following allows for appending to the DOM as expected:

```
echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Photo'] );
```