# BLOB data fails to be written to a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I created a database that stores various data about an image as well as the image itself. I have five keys `(id, name, size, format, file)`. The `id` is auto-incrementable. The `file` is a value of a BLOB type - `(mediumblob)`. Rest is of its respective type. The weird thing is that every other variable is successfully written to the database except for the BLOB image itself.

Wait for the user to upload an image using `$_POST`:

```
if(isset($_POST['file_one_submit'])){
    $post = 'file_one_input';
}
```

Define all the variables. Including the `$file` variable with:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES[$post]['tmp_name']);
```

Then I make a query to replace the record in the database with the new information:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("REPLACE INTO `images` (id, name, size, format, file) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt -> bind_param("isisb", $id, $name, $size, $format, $file);
$stmt -> execute();
```

After the query's been executed all records in the database successfully get updated with the exception of the `file` column which should contain the BLOB data. I thought that the `$post` variable may be incorrectly defined but getting the name of the uploaded file for instance works:

```
upload_name = $_FILES[$post]['name'];
```

I've tried to echo the `$file` variable to check its contents and got presented with a long rubbish of data which I assume is the proper string generated during the conversion to BLOB with the `file_get_contents()` function.

I've checked that the size of the file does not exceed the capabilities of the `mediumblob` BLOB type. I've also attempted to check for errors in my code with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql#20564797) post without success. No errors or warnings appear on the page when the code is run. I've also enabled error/warning checks with `E_STRICT` but still, no output was presented.

Comment: What is the value of `file` in the record you end up with and what was the value you wanted to store? Also, please run `show create table images` in your database and show us what the table looks alike.

Comment: You left out very important information from your question. What is the size of `max_allowed_packet` on your server and what is the size in bytes of your `$file`. Please add this information to the question.

Comment: What will you use the file for?  If it will be used in a web page, see my Answer.  If it will be used some other way, I may have a different suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by using `send_long_data` method.
(*in these examples I have removed some irrelevant columns for the example*).

### Option 1: Use send_long_data method for passing binary data

The benefit of using `b` according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php:

> Note:
>
> If data size of a variable exceeds max. allowed packet size
> (max_allowed_packet), you have to specify b in types and use
> mysqli_stmt_send_long_data() to send the data in packets.

```php
//...

if(isset($_POST['file_one_submit'])){
    $post = 'file_one_input';

    $id = 1;
    $file = NULL;

    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("REPLACE INTO `images` (id, file) VALUES(?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("ib", $id, $file);
    
    //send_long_data(int $param_num, string $data): bool
    $stmt->send_long_data(1, file_get_contents($_FILES[$post]['tmp_name'])); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>

<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_one_input" />
    <input type="submit" name="file_one_submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

### Option 2: Change b to s

I think it is better to use b, but if I changed b to s (string) this also seems to be working:

```php
//...

if(isset($_POST['file_one_submit'])){
    $post = 'file_one_input';

    $id = 1;
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES[$post]['tmp_name']);

    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("REPLACE INTO `images` (id, file) VALUES(?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $file);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>

<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_one_input" />
    <input type="submit" name="file_one_submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Upon changing "b" as "blob" to "s" as "string" everything works and the BLOB data gets successfully written. I get that BLOB is basically just a pile of "string" data but then it gets me confused as to what is the "b" data type actually used for if passing "s" instead of "b" does work but not otherwise? That would mean that the "b" option would be entirely useless... I've figured this is a solution myself an hour later but since you mentioned the same one also I will mark this as an answer considering that this is probably not entirely wrong to do then? Thanks for pointing this out. Will have

Comment: That is correct answer. Thanks for reading the documentation and providing it. I will provide explanation as another answer.

Comment: With b the data will be sent in packets, to avoid exceeding max allowed packet size. So this is the benefit of b.

Answer (score 1):

Option `b` is used for sending data in batches. It's used when your data size exceeds `max_allowed_packet` (16MB by default). You must then use the method [`send_long_data()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php) to send the data in packets.

```
// $file should be set to NULL
$stmt->bind_param("ssssb", $id, $name, $size, $format, $file);
$fp = fopen($_FILES[$post]['tmp_name'], "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(4, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
```

When you are sure that your blob data will never exceed the limit, you can safely bind it as a string. By default, you should bind every variable as a string (`s`) as the type doesn't matter in most cases. Binding everything as a string is easier and safer 99% of the time.

<sub>Usually, I recommend PDO as the easier solution, but even when using [PDO with large objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php), you still have to handle streams in a similar manner.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If the image is for a web page, I recommend *not* storing the image in the database.  Instead, write to a file in tree of other web pages/files.  Then build `<img src=$path>` where $path is relative to the root for web files.

This avoids the nasties being asked about in this Question, makes the database a little more efficient, and actually speeds up delivering web pages.

Put the path in the table so that you can build the img tag when building the web page.

Answer (score 0):

So you can manipulate it using the PHP Streams API.

```
$conn = new PDO('database settings');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO `images` (id, name, size, format, file) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");


$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($file_tmp, 'rb');

$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_FILES['file']['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(3, filesize($file_tmp));
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_FILES['file']['type']);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();
```

This example opens up a file and passes the file handle to PDO to insert it as a LOB. PDO will do its best to get the contents of the file up to the database in the most efficient manner possible.

More detail is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)