# retrieving image form database in Blob data type

Tags: php, base64, blob, signature

Can any one help me and tell me what am
I doing wrong here, I can't seem to figure out why cant I get the signature on html page
Here is the code I am working with....

```
<?php
include('config.php');


$sql = "SELECT signature FROM details WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$id = "116"; // Replace with the ID of the signature data to retrieve
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

// Fetch the result and return the base64-encoded signature data
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result) {
    $signatureData = $result['signature'];
    $base64Data = base64_encode($signatureData);
    $img = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'>';
    echo $img;

  } else {
    echo "No signature data found for ID $id";
  }
  ?>
```

I am trying to display signature on html form which is in the database

Comment: You made the `$base64Data` variable but never used it. You've told your `<img>` tag what type of image, but not *which* image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but still I can't seem to display the image
echo $img = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $base64Data . '" width="100px" height="100px">';

Comment: you mean this right

echo $img = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $base64Data . '" width="100px" height="100px">';